# Scheduling a job in pentaho 5.1 setting logging information to Email

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-design-studio, pdi

In pentaho [PDI(Kettle)] 5.1 version after scheduling job i have set email to the transformation in job if job fails email has send to the mail where the error occured.If i want to see detailed log information what happening during scheduling. How to set that please help me in this issue

E:\PENTAHO\data-integration\Kitchen.bat /file:E:\PENTAHO\rml_app_profile.kjb  ./rml_app_profile.kjb.log

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of getting the logging level:

1. Using the level argument:: **/level:Detailed** like:

   `kitchen.bat /file:E:\someKettleJob.kjb /level:Detailed`
2. You can use the Kettle logging system itself to get the detailed logging (in the Transformation settings). Check the image below

[image]

In your case, you can modify your code as below:

`E:\PENTAHO\data-integration\Kitchen.bat /file:E:\PENTAHO\rml_app_profile.kjb /level:Detailed >> E:\rml_app_profile.log`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: For above it is attaching the log information in mail. With out attachment if i want to get log information to my mail.Is any another way.

Comment: One possible way is to schedule a different Job (once the master job is over), which would read all the log files (error ones) and do a substring of the error section (if there is any error). Send this string section as a Mail Body to your mail address. You can even do the same using either shell or bat scripts.

Comment: Can u explain me it more detail please

Comment: Read all the log files which your Job is generating. Search for String "Error". If you find any Error, do a string of some desired length (may be of some 100 characters). Next assign a variable to this result and use the Mail body step to send it in a mail comment section. If you need, i can share some sample code :)

Comment: I have done a sample code. Its in the link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6NvpRn8XxcFem9UcGRvWkNjMk0&authuser=0 .I have coded for a single log file. Start from the "ErrorLogCheckerMasterJob.kjb". Please let me know if you are not able to view the code.

Comment: @Rishu your ktr read this file ${Internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory}/log.log Is a defult file created by pentaho or another ktr must create it?

Comment: @JRichardsz it is not created by ktr and is a user specific log file name